# Use Python requests to filter Azure DevOps Services REST API agent pools

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

What specific changes need to be made to the below code in order to successfully filter the list of Agent Pools by the properties `name` and `isHosted` using the Python requests module and the Azure DevOps Services REST API endpoint documented [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)?

Only 1 agent pool should be returned when the list is filtered by `{name=Default,isHosted=false}` as shown below, but the problem is that the code below is returning ALL agent pools including those with different names and those that are Hosted.

```
import requests
import os
import base64
import json 

personal_access_token = ":"+os.environ["AZ_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
headers = {}
headers['Content-type'] = "application/json"
headers['Authorization'] = b'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8'))

#Get a list of agent pools.
instance = "dev.azure.com/MyOrganization"
propVals = "{name=Default,isHosted=false}"
api_version = "5.1"
url = ("https://%s/_apis/distributedtask/pools?properties=%s?api-version=%s" % (instance, propVals, api_version))

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  

print("r.status_code is: ", r.status_code)
print("r.json() is: ", r.json())
```

Note there seems to be very little documentation of how to use Python to integrate with the Azure DevOps Services API.  Also, note we are using Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters) you provided if you want to get only 1 pool you can  use the following URL parameter (instead of `properties`):

```
poolName={poolName}
```

And not just `name=` like in your code: `propVals = "{name=Default,isHosted=false}"`.

In addition, I don't see any parameter of `isHosted` and I don't think you need it, because if you use `poolName` you will get only one pool anyway.

So, update your code to: `propVals = "poolName=Default"` because your final URL should be:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName={poolName}&api-version=5.1
```

Note: `&api-version=5.1` and not `?api-version=5.1`

Comment: The actual URL that worked (processed here by Python) was `url = ("https://dev.azure.com/%s/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName=%s&api-version=%s" % (azuredevops_organization_name, poolName, api_version))` .  Note the `%s` which clearly articulates the removal of `{`curly braces`}` which was probably implied in your answer.